# What do I have to do to set C++ development in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am currently trying to set my eclipse so that I can start c++ development on my Windows computer. However, I am stuck with some errors. But first, here is what I did so far:

- Installed the CDT for Eclipse
- Installed Cygwin (with the additional packages `gcc`, `gcc` and `make`)
- Added all "paths for headers" in Eclipse

The problem is that when I try to run my Hello World program, I get `Launch failed. Binary not found.`

I already build and rebuild the project but the program is still not running. It must be because of these errors that I have:

- `/bin/sh: g++: command not found`
- `make: ***[src/HelloWorld.o] Error 127`

What can I do to solve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Cygwin setup.exe again and select the packages for g++.  Search for that and make sure those are installed.  It should be under the name `gcc-g++`.  The C++ compiler is installed separately from the C compiler.

Comment: did a reinstall of gcc-g++ but that didn't help. the error still occurs

Comment: That's strange.  Can you open a cygwin terminal and type `g++` to make sure it's working there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out by myself. Since this really freaked me out, I want anyone else who has this problem to know how I solved it.

So apparently, since I had g++, gcc and all that installed, it had to be a problem with the path.
So what I did was check my path. If you don't know how to edit it, check this link http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

So in there, I chose `Path` under the System variables and clicked on `Edit...`. What I noticed was that instead of `C:\cygwin64` it said `C:\cygwin`. All I did was append the 64 (since I had installed the 64-bit version of cygwin) and I was done.

I restarted Eclipse, cleaned and built the project and the errors where gone!